# Django - Show history in admin working but only when actions take place in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin, when you are looking at a record there is a button called "history".  When you click on this button, it tells you when the record was created and by whom and also each time a field was changed and by whom.  I find this extremely useful.  However, I noted that these only show up for actions that are done on the admin page.  So when I change the record through a view, this is not displayed in that history.  Is there an easy way to have my views store this information also so that it will all be visible from the admin page?

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The admin app comes with a model - `LogEntry`. Every time you do something in the admin app, there is some code somewhere that saves a `LogEntry`. This is how the app works. For example in the `changeform_view` there is something like this:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, ...):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
            # do some other stuff then
            self.log_change(request, new_object, change_message)

def log_change(self, request, object, message):
    """
    Log that an object has been successfully changed.

    The default implementation creates an admin LogEntry object.
    """
    from django.contrib.admin.models import CHANGE, LogEntry
    return LogEntry.objects.log_action(
        user_id=request.user.pk,
        content_type_id=get_content_type_for_model(object).pk,
        object_id=object.pk,
        object_repr=str(object),
        action_flag=CHANGE,
        change_message=message,
    )
```

`LogEntry.objects.log_action` is where the log is created. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen anywhere else, unless you were to make it happen.

There's nothing stopping you from doing this though. You can create a `LogEntry` wherever you want.

Having said that, it might be a bit confusing since when you see a `LogEntry` you now no longer no if that is a change that has happened because of someone manually changing some data via the admin app, or a change that has occurred programatically. It would probably be a better idea to create your own `Log` model, and save logs where and when you want.

You can always display your Logs in your in the relevant admin view should you so wish. Something like this will do the trick:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = (logs_field,)

    def logs_field(self, instance):
        logs = Log.objects.filter(object=instance)
        return format_html_join(
            '\n', "<p>{}: {}</p>",
            ((log.date, log.message) for log in logs)
        )
```